# Having problems making a command that allows people to turn the blacklist on and off

Tags: discord.js

I thought that allowing people to turn my blacklist on and off for their server would be kinda neat, but I didn't find much success so far. Also I was wondering, is it hard to make a command that allows people to add their own words to the blacklist? Here's the code:

```
  let blacklisted = ['bad words here'] 

  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in blacklisted) { 
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
  }

    if (foundInText) {
      message.delete();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a variable for turning on or off the blacklist. BacklistOn = true, And use a if statement before the code you copied in here. Then make a command that changes that variable. You would need to store the variable in a JSON file if you want the setting to be saved when restarting the bot or if the bot crashes. Tutorial on reading/writing to JSON with node.js https://medium.com/@osiolabs/read-write-json-files-with-node-js-92d03cc82824